# Commas displaying on Windows boot screen

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop

I have an HP Pavilion G6 laptop and there are comma marks displaying in the boot screen:

[image]

I changed the hard disk and RAM, but the result is the same. This only happens in the boot screen, I can't see these marks after Windows starts loading, and the blue screen error occurred several times.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by defective hardware, possibly the graphics card.

Many HP laptops have the HP System Diagnostics software built into the BIOS. The [tool's description](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01443317#AbT3) from HP's site is:

> The System Diagnostics window allows you to run several diagnostic tests. Each test determines if the hardware is functioning properly, and displays an error message and a warranty ID if there is a hardware failure.

Here are the instructions for accessing the diagnostics and running the tests:

1. Turn off the computer.
2. Use one of the following methods to open the HP System Diagnostics:

   - Turn on the computer and immediately press the F2 key repeatedly, about once every second, until the HP System Diagnostics program opens.
   - Turn on the computer and immediately press the Escape key repeatedly, about once every second, until the Startup menu opens. Then press F2.